how do i make a window panned tkinter GUI
here is my code.
with it I can open and play an album of lovely music, which displays the tracks on the vertical black left hand pane.
I have been trying to make said window "pannable" so i can drag/ expand it to the right to display any text that has been cut off.
This is just a hobby for me so excuse the lack of knowledge/ etiquette.
this is my code

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pygame
import os
import customtkinter as ctk 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Music Player')
pygame.mixer.init()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)   

songs = []
curent_song = ""
paused = False



def load_music():
    global current_song
    root.directory = filedialog.askdirectory()

    for song in os.listdir(root.directory):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(song)
        if ext == '.mp3':
            songs.append(song)

    for song in songs:
        songlist.insert("end", song)

    songlist.selection_set(0)
    current_song = songs [songlist.curselection()[0]]

def play_music():
    global current_song, paused

    if not paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(root.directory, current_song))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        paused = False

def pause_music():
    global paused
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    paused = True



def next_music():
    global current_song, paused


    try:
        songlist.selection_clear(0, END)
        songlist.selection_set(songs.index(current_song) + 1)
        current_song = songs[songlist.curselection()[0]]
        play_music()
    except:
        pass

def previous_music():
    global current_song, paused

    try:
        songlist.selection_clear(0, END)
        songlist.selection_set(songs.index(current_song) -1)
        current_song = songs[songlist.curselection()[0]]
        play_music()
    except:
        pass

organise_menu = Menu(menubar , tearoff=False)
organise_menu.add_command(label='select Folder' , command=load_music)
menubar.add_cascade(label='organise' , menu=organise_menu)


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   STYLING


s = ttk.Style()

s.configure('mainFrame.TFrame',     background = '#7FFF00') #GREEN
s.configure('Frame2.TFrame',        background = '#FF1493') #PINK!
s.configure('Frame3.TFrame',        background = '#FF1493') #PINK!
s.configure('Frame4.TFrame',        background = '#7FFF00')#GREEN


s.configure('Frame5.TFrame',        background = '#7FFF00')#GREEN
s.configure('Frame6.TFrame',        background = '#FF1493')#PINK!
s.configure('Frame7.TFrame',        background = '#FF1493')#PINK!
s.configure('Frame8.TFrame',        background = '#7FFF00')#GREEN
s.configure('Horizontal.TFrame',    background = '#CDC5BF')
s.configure('Verticle.TFrame',      background = '#FFD93L')




#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   WIDGETS

mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style='mainFrame.TFrame')
mainFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame2 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame2.TFrame')
Frame2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame3 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame3.TFrame')
Frame3.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame4 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame4.TFrame')
Frame4.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame5 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame5.TFrame')
Frame5.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame6 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame6.TFrame')
Frame6.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame7 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame7.TFrame')
Frame7.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame8 = ttk.Frame(root, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame8.TFrame')
Frame8.grid(row = 1, column = 4, sticky = 'NSEW')


songlist = Listbox(root, bg="black", fg="white", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=25 , height=15)
songlist.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'NSEW')






#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   GRID CONFIGURATION

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 2)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight = 2)
root.columnconfigure(3, weight = 2)
root.columnconfigure(4, weight = 2)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight = 0)


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ BUTTONS

play_btn_image = PhotoImage(file='play.png')
pause_btn_image = PhotoImage(file='pause.png')
next_btn_image = PhotoImage(file='next.png')
back_btn_image = PhotoImage(file='back.png')

control_frame = Frame(root)
control_frame.grid()

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~CHANGED .PACK TO .GRID

play_btn = Button(control_frame, image=play_btn_image, borderwidth=0, command=play_music)
pause_btn = Button(control_frame, image=pause_btn_image, borderwidth=0, command=pause_music)
next_btn = Button(control_frame, image=next_btn_image, borderwidth=0, command=next_music)
back_btn = Button(control_frame, image=back_btn_image, borderwidth=0, command=previous_music)


play_btn.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=7, pady=10)
pause_btn.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=7, pady=10)
next_btn.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=7, pady=10)
back_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=7, pady=10)





root.mainloop()

I have tried rearranging multiple lines of code, sometimes i get error messages, other times i get the windows/ widgets i want but everything goes out of place.
screenshot

The code is there mate

You can use PanedWindow and put the Listbox at the left pane and all those color frames in another frame which is put in the right pane.
...

# PanedWindow
paned = ttk.PanedWindow(root, orient="horizontal")
paned.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew") # put at row 0 column 0

songlist = Listbox(paned, bg="black", fg="white", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, width=25 , height=15)
# frame for those colorful frames
widget_frame = ttk.Frame(paned)

paned.add(songlist)     # add to left pane
paned.add(widget_frame) # add to right pane

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   WIDGETS in widget_frame

# create colorful frames as children of widget_frame

mainFrame = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style='mainFrame.TFrame')
mainFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame2 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame2.TFrame')
Frame2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame3 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame3.TFrame')
Frame3.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame4 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame4.TFrame')
Frame4.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame5 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame5.TFrame')
Frame5.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame6 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame6.TFrame')
Frame6.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame7 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame7.TFrame')
Frame7.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = 'NSEW')

Frame8 = ttk.Frame(widget_frame, width = 250, height = 250, style = 'Frame8.TFrame')
Frame8.grid(row = 1, column = 3, sticky = 'NSEW')

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   GRID CONFIGURATION

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

...

control_frame = Frame(root)
control_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew") # put at row 1 column 0

...

You can then resize the listbox horizontally using the vertical handle of the PanedWindow widget:



Nice one acw1668 I’ll have a look when I’m back tonight.thanks very much
